# How could I use machine learning to search for components in technical drawings?

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation, engineering-statistics

I have a very large library of technical drawings (in image only format) specifically of mechanical parts, grouped in bundles.

The drawings have various levels of cleanliness since some were hand drawn and some come from CAD software. The drawings may have line linking annotations to the object itself.

I would like to select the components with more or less certain shapes within the library.

Is there any machine learning tool I could use for the purpose?

For example, a drawing could look like:

[image: drawing]

and I may want to search for the component number 1 by mentioning it has a shape overall curve, with a recess on one side.

(if another site of SE is better suited to the question please migrate or mention in the comment, I'll delete and repost)